# Undocumented GHC flags -fbuilding-cabal-package and --package-db

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

The output of `cabal build --verbose` mentions flags that are not documented in the man pages.  GHC is given a flag `-fbuilding-cabal-package`.  `ghc-pkg` is given a flag `--package-db`.  My guess is that the latter is a synonym for `--package-conf`.  Am I right?  And what is the former?

Answer (score 2):

`--package-db` is documented in the [user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html?highlight=package-db#ghc-flag--package-db%20%E2%9F%A8file%E2%9F%A9). It is indeed similar to the old `--package-conf` flag, see [user guide for older ghc](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases).

`-fbuilding-cabal-package` is indeed undocumented, there is a [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9358) about that. It is designed to be used by cabal only. It changes few [compiler messages](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f63bc730c7ea42ca6882f8078eb86be8bf1cc6ad/compiler/main/GhcMake.hs#L203) to look more clear when building package using cabal.

Comment: I'm talking about `ghc-pkg` not `ghc`.  `-package-db` (with one leading `-`) *is* mentioned in `man ghc`.  `--package-db` (with two) is *not* mentioned in `man ghc-pkg`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. In that case you probably should create a ticket on their track.